# Angular get component size

Tags: angular, angular-router

Using @angular/router 5.0.5,

When it's safe to get the component height/width ? (without being aware that @angular/router is used if possible).

`ngAfterViewInit` doesn't work because right after switching to the page, there is two `ng-component` rendered *at the same time*. The previous page and the new one:

[image]

Since I'm using flex, it's splitting in half the size of my component... Way too quick to see it of course, but enough to get the wrong size.

I suppose that angular do that to allow some kind of transition.

`setTimeout` inside `ngAfterViewInit` works fine, but is there anything better than that ?

(I'm really surprised that nobody talk about this behavior, am I doing something wrong ?)

Answer (score 0):

Best way I found so far is to get the size inside NgZone.onStable (in `ngAfterViewInit`) :

```
this.zone.onStable.pipe(first()).subscribe(() => {
// get the component size here
}
```